# Is there a way to set/edit unity shortcuts from code?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, keyboard-shortcuts, unity-editor, unity3d-editor

i'm trying to set-up a shortcut for a unity item from code.
More specifically the Stage/Go Back for the prefab editor.
I know, it's possible (recommendable, even) to edit shortcuts manually, but for what i'm trying to make would be really helpful if it was possible to activate or deactivate the shortcut from code.

I've tried using `EditorApplication.ExecuteMenuItem("Stage/Go back");` but it doesn't work with that one.

If it's not possible to do it I'll understand it, thank you!

Comment: Have a look into the [Shortcut Manager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ShortcutsManager.html) and according [API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ShortcutManagement.ShortcutManager-instance.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to user [derHugo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7111561/derhugo) i found the [API to shortcut management](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ShortcutManagement.ShortcutManager.html) and after a few minutes understanding the code I finally was able to do it. I'll leave the code here in case anyone needs to know how I did this.

```
/*You need to access ShortcutManager's instance and call to RebindShortcut
RebindShortcut works by passing the id(string) of the shortcut to modify and a KeyCombination
KeyCombination accepts the keyCode and modifier like Shift or Action(Ctrl)
*/
KeyCombination keyCombination = new KeyCombination(KeyCode.O, ShortcutModifiers.Shift); // I don't know how to add more than one modifiers
ShortcutManager.instance.RebindShortcut("Stage/Go Back", new ShortcutBinding(keyCombination));
```